# Grab object where key is a certain value

Tags: java, hashmap

Within my java application I have a hashmap that holds a string and an Integer. I'm in a situation where I need to return an object where the key is a certain value. I'm not sure how I would go about doing this. Your support would be greatly appreciated.

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> loginArenaList = new HashMap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`Map#get(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
loginArenaList.get(key);
```

BTW, your declaration of map is wrong. You are missing generics type on RHS. And of course, you should declare the reference as `private`, unless you have strong reasons to use `public`. Should be:

```
private Map<String, Integer> loginArenaList = new HashMap<>(); // In Java 7
```

Comment: I thought get was only used to return the object? Thanks for the heads-up with the declaration.

Comment: @AndrewZak. And try using interface types for reference. Like `Map` in this case.

Comment: @RohitJain alright.How about the inverse? If I need to return the key where the object is a certain value?

Comment: @AndrewZak. You would have to iterate through your map in that case.

Answer (score 0):

According to the declared map, your keys are of type String and the object to be retrieved is of type Integer. Assuming that you have the key in the variable "key", all you have to do is use the [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

loginArenaList.get(key);